# Maven add natives to library path

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl, pom.xml

I want to include LWJGL via Maven in my project. I get the `.jar` files but the natives are not in the classpath.

With the help of google I found out that I should use `mavennatives` in order to automatically extract and copy the natives. However `mavennatives` will only find the natives that start with `native-` and the LWJGL-natives all have names like `{artifactId}-{version}-natives-{os}.jar`.

**Question**: How can I get Maven to import the dependencies with the proper names and extract these natives?

My `pom.xml`:

```
<project ... >
     ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpacknatives</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0a</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0a</version>
            <classifier>natives-linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0a</version>
            <classifier>natives-windows</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mavennatives/) of the plugin:

> This plugin unpacks every dependency with a classifier beginning with `natives-`.

That's exactly your use case, the documentation points to the [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) element, which in your case is `natives-linux` or `natives-windows`.

Accordingo to the documentation, theses cases will be handled:

> This are the default values, when enabling separateDirs the plugin will unpack each native dependency to a subdir of the nativesTargetDir named like its classifier (for example: `natives-windows` will go to `target/natives/windows`)

Indeed the whole library's jar is in the form of `{artifactId}-{version}-natives-{os}.jar` but in Maven the classifier is exactly the string between the `{version}` and the extension of the file: in this case `natives-{os}`, which starts by `natives` and as such is handled by the library.

Comment: okay, does this mean it should work the way I set it up? But why is it not working then?

Comment: How are you invoking maven? Do you see the plugin executed as part of your build?

Comment: I use it in intellij. But when I just run Maven-Build the plugin is not executed.... executing the plugin alone helped